# scroll target div when dragging from a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Given 2 divs, both of which are auto scroll.
I want to be able to drag an item from Div1 into Div2, or internally within Div1.

Items will never be in Div2 - the drop event on Div2 will take care placing it into the correct place on Div1

So far that's easy enough but here's the snag - Div2 needs to be able to scroll vertically while dragging.

I can't find anything in the jQuery draggable that helps here so I tried to create my own hover regions which cause a scroll on Div2. This works when not dragging but not while dragging. I suspect jQuery is stealing the event causing mine not to fire.

html:

```
<div id="Outer">
  <div id="Div1">
    <div class='Item'></div>
    <div class='Item'></div>
    <div class='Item'></div>
  </div>

  <div id="Div2">
    <div class="ScrollUp"></div>
    some long content that causes a scrollbar
    <div class="ScrollDown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#Div1, #Div2
{
   overflow: auto;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#Div1>.Item').draggable({appendTo: $('#Outer')});
$('#Div1').droppable({tolerance: 'pointer'});
$('#Div2').droppable({drop: Div2Drop});
function Div2Drop() {}; //function places the item into the approriate place in Div1 
$('#ScrollUp, #ScrollDown').mouseenter(function(){... });  /* These 2 events don't */
$('#ScrollUp, #ScrollDown').mouseout(function(){... });    /* fire when dragging */
```

Div1 also needs to be scrollable when dragging internally.

How can I make the events fire, or is there a better way to do this? (Perhaps something internal to the draggable and droppable interactions that I missed?

Comment: Somewhat randomly this seems to be working now even though I haven't changed anything. Odd